# Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik, pagerequestmanager

This is the strangest issue i have ever had in my programming life, I have spent two days looking for solutions to the below exception, but i couldn't find out where it's happening.

In Asp.net 4.5 application, I have Crafts.aspx on the root folder, in this page i have some ajax requests and it's working fine.

I have copied the page exactly as it's to Crafts2.aspx, no any change but the name.
The problem is, Any page name other that Crafts.aspx will throw the below exception and breakpoints are not working for it in debugging mode.

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled. Details: Error parsing near ' <!DOCTYPE html>
```

I couldn't find any reason for this exception, both pages are exactly the same in design and code behind, the only difference is the page name,  Where's the Reasonable Suspicion in such problem?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `action` attribute from the `form` will solve the problem:

Before:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" action="./">
```

After:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" >
```